# Partial derivatives of $A^n x$ with respect to the entries of $A$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$. I am wondering what the partial derivative of each entry of $A^n x$ with respect to the entries of $A$ is. Is there a closed form expression for this?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{i,j}} A^nx$$

I wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: See e.g. [scalar-by-matrix derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix) for information on how to interpret this kind of object.

Comment: yes you are of course correct, sorry. I meant a partial derivative with respect to the entries of A. Does this clarify what I mean?

Comment: does this still not make sense?

Comment: I don't know, but I would be surprised if there is a nice answer to this for arbitrary $A$ and $x$. The entries of $A^n$ are awkward to describe for a generic matrix, being a nonlinear combination of entries of $A$, and then $A^n x$ is a linear combination of those nonlinear combinations. So unless $A$, $x$, or both (in relation to each other, like $x$ being an eigenvector or something) are nice, probably there isn't a pretty expression?

Comment: there are no nice relations between A and x so yes, I was looking at the general case. I have been manually going through small n to look for a pattern. n=1 is trivial, n=2 is doable but at n=3 im getting lost in algebra. Thanks a lot for your input, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe by way of answer: it's certainly possible to describe the entries of $A^n$ (see e.g. [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373529/formula-for-the-entry-of-a-matrix-power)) and so $A^n x$ is easily expressible in terms of them; then differentiate with respect to one of the original entries in $A$. Won't be pretty though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Letting $e_k$ be $k$-th standard basis vector, the derivative is
$$
\boxed{
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}} \left[A^{n}x\right]=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^{k}e_i e_j^\intercal A^{n-k-1}\right)x
}
$$

### Derivation

For brevity, define $E=e_{i}e_{j}^{\intercal}$ and $\partial_{ij}\equiv\partial / \partial A_{ij}$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
\partial_{ij}\left[A^{n}\right] & =\partial_{ij}\left[AA^{n-1}\right]\\
 & =\partial_{ij}\left[A\right]A^{n-1}+A\partial_{ij}\left[A^{n-1}\right]\\
 & =EA^{n-1}+A\partial_{ij}\left[A^{n-1}\right].
\end{align*}
Therefore, by induction,
\begin{align*}
\partial_{ij}\left[A^{n}\right] & =EA^{n-1}+A\partial_{ij}\left[A^{n-1}\right]\\
 & =EA^{n-1}+AEA^{n-2}+A^{2}\partial_{ij}\left[A^{n-2}\right]\\
 & =\cdots\\
 & =EA^{n-1}+AEA^{n-2}+\cdots+A^{n-1}EA^{n-n}+A^{n}\partial_{ij}\left[A^{n-n}\right]\\
 & =EA^{n-1}+AEA^{n-2}+\cdots+A^{n-1}E\\
 & =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^{k}EA^{n-k-1}.
\end{align*}

### Verification

Here is some code to numerically verify (with finite differences) 1000 random instances.
Note that in the code, the matrix powers are **not** computed efficiently.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power as mpow
import pytest

n_params = 1000
params = zip(
    np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=n_params),
    np.random.randint(1, high=4, size=n_params),
    np.random.uniform(size=n_params),
    np.random.uniform(size=n_params),
)
params = list(params)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('m,n,i_frac,j_frac', params)
def test_formula(m, n, i_frac, j_frac, h=1e-6, rtol=1e-3):
    i = int(i_frac * m)
    j = int(j_frac * m)

    A = np.random.randn(m, m)
    x = np.random.randn(m)

    e_i = np.zeros(m)
    e_j = np.zeros(m)
    e_i[i] = 1.
    e_j[j] = 1.
    E = np.outer(e_i, e_j)

    # Compute derivative using formula.
    D = sum(mpow(A, i) @ E @ mpow(A, n - i - 1) for i in range(0, n))
    exact = D @ x

    # Compute derivative numerically.
    delta = mpow(A + h * E, n) @ x - mpow(A, n) @ x
    approx = delta / h

    np.testing.assert_allclose(exact, approx, rtol=rtol)
```

Comment: amazing thank you so much. I was just numerically checking this in numpy to make sure I had understood!

Comment: If you end up using this for serious computation, make sure to be efficient about the computation of matrix powers. In particular, since you need every matrix power up to $n-1$ for this formula, use the relation $A^k = A A^{k-1}$ to compute each power and store it (assuming memory is not an issue). It should be noted that if accuracy is not an issue, finite differences should be faster for $n$ sufficiently large since you can use the relation $A^{2k} = A^k A^k$.

Comment: Another important point to mention for efficiency is that $E$ only has a single nonzero entry and hence you can perform the multiplications $A^a E A^b$ more efficiently than by dense multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the differential
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\mathbf{u}
&=&
(d\mathbf{A}^n) \mathbf{x}
=
\left[
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\mathbf{A}^{k} (d\mathbf{A}) \mathbf{A}^{n-1-k} 
\right] \mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray*}
Since
$\mathbf{A}=
\sum_{i,j}
A_{ij} \mathbf{E}_{ij}$,
we simply write
$
d\mathbf{A}
=
(dA_{ij}) \mathbf{E}_{ij}
$
where
$
\mathbf{E}_{ij} =
\mathbf{e}_i \mathbf{e}_j^T$.
Finally
$$
d\mathbf{u}
=
dA_{ij}\cdot
\left[
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\mathbf{A}^{k} \mathbf{E}_{ij} \mathbf{A}^{n-1-k} 
\right] 
\mathbf{x}
$$
which gives the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial A_{ij}}
=
\left[
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\mathbf{A}^{k} \mathbf{E}_{ij} \mathbf{A}^{n-1-k} 
\right] 
\mathbf{x}
$$

Comment: Nice, +1.
Here's [a handy guide with many differential identities](http://ce.sharif.edu/courses/93-94/1/ce717-2/resources/root/Review/minka-matrix.pdf) for OP.